# AWS ALB triggers Lambda but no response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, permissions, amazon-elb

I have a an AWS Application Load Balancer with a target group that contains a lambda.

When I use the public ipv4 address of the load balancer the browser gets no response.

I can see from CloudWatch that the Lambda function is getting triggered - but no response is getting back to the browser.

Do I need special permissions on the Load Balancer or Lambda?

Any help much appreciated.

The Lambda code is:

```py
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("event")
    print (event)
    return {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "statusDescription": "200 OK",
    "isBase64Encoded": False,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "text/html"
    },
    "body": "<h1>Hello from Lambda!</h1>"
}
```

Comment: Are you returning correct respose from lambda? Maybe it crashes? You don't need special permissions, appart from the invocation one which is automatically created if you setup ALB+lambda in console.

Comment: Can you show us your lambda code

Comment: I have a Lambda called LambdaForLoadBalancer,  a Load Balancer callerd LoadBalancerForLambda and a target group called TargetGroupForLB. Policy for the Lambda is:

Comment: {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AWS-ALB_Invoke-TargetGroupForLB-b7381ec052487fbc",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:776504653196:function:LambdaForLoadBalancer",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:776504653196:targetgroup/TargetGroupForLB/b7381ec052487fbc"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Lambda code is:  import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("event")
    print (event)
    return {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "statusDescription": "200 OK",
    "isBase64Encoded": False,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "text/html"
    },
    "body": "<h1>Hello from Lambda!</h1>"
}

Comment: did u manage to know the reason, I am having the same issue?